# Deleting previous events with esper cep

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper

While sending events to the runtime if some condition applies I want to ignore all past events and start fresh (with the same runtime, pattern, listeners, etc.), and that could happen many times so i need a relatively fast way of doing that. Is there a function that deletes from the runtime all the events that were already sent (I couldn't find such function in the documentation)? (I know I could create a new runtime but that is very time consuming)

Answer (score 0):

Yes the contexts; You define the start condition and end condition. When the end condition is reached the runtime throws away all state, [doc link](http://esper.espertech.com/release-8.4.0/reference-esper/html_single/index.html#context_def_nonoverlapping).

Comment: I'm looking for a java function I can call in my code, not something in the pattern

Comment: There is no need to use a pattern for the end condition and any event will do. There is no java api other than events.